# Oracle Apps : could not find a price list in order uom or primary uom

Tags: oracle-apps

---

**could not find a price list in order uom or primary uom**

---

I am getting error when set item to order line details.

Comment: This question is related to Oracle Apps

Answer (score 0):

**Navigation To Fix the Issue**

Pricing --> Price List --> Price List Set up
[image]

- Click on to Qualifiers.
- Check the Grouping Number and the Qualifier Context.
- For a Basic Transaction with out Qualifiers.
- Enter the Grouping Number as -1 and save the Price List.
- Qualifier Context is a Manditatory Field but the system will allow you to save with out any values.